# Scss, tagert class and aslo active class

Tags: css, sass

Im sure this is very simple.

is there a better way to write this is SCSS

```
.tab,
.tab.active {
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 0 5px 8px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
.tab {
    &,
    &.active {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    }
}
```

But unless your not overriding an existing `.active`, then `.tab.active` will inherit from `.tab` and this would be enough:

```
.tab {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 8px;
}
```

Comment: For his example, SCSS is more markup than CSS, but if there are subchildren and whatnot, then the SCSS method would be better.

Comment: Perfect, yes im overriding an exisiting .active

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
.tab{
  //some styles
  &.active{
   margin:0;
   padding:5px 0 5px 8px;
  }
}
```

Comment: would not just apply this stuff to class="tab active" and not class="tab" ?

Comment: Can you say that again? I don't think I understand you. You have misspelling. @Richy